# Logic Pro X Feature For Monster Voices

Tags: logic-pro, effects

There's a plugin that you can purchase called [Dehumaniser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBsuYXosOhk) that allows you to speak into a mic and it applies some sort of animal sound (or sounds) to your voice. So you can combine a bunch of sounds to create monster voices, etc. I know that Logic Pro X has a vocoder, but I was wondering if it has any features that allow you to map a sound (like a dog or a horse) onto your voice. So when I speak through the mic it should sound like a dog is speaking.

Comment: Isn't a vocoder a thing that maps a sound onto your voice?

Comment: Yes, but it's a synth sound only...at least that's how it is with the Logic Pro X vocoder. I edited the question to be a little more specific.